# Magento: Product image in header cart

Tags: magento, cart

I would like to display the simple product image in my header cart.

`Admin->Configuration->Shopping Cart->Configurable Product` is set on `Product Thumbnail Itself`. This works for the main cart, but the header cart is still displaying the parent image.

This is the code for the header cart:

```html
<div class="block-content" id="panel">
 <div class="top_arrow"></div>
  <div class="cart_topbg">
  <div class="main-cart">
  <?php $_items = $this->getRecentItems() ?>
  <?php if(count($_items)): ?>
   <p class="block-subtitle"><?php echo $this->__('Recently added item(s)') ?></p>
   <ol id="cart-sidebar" class="mini-products-list">
   <?php foreach($_items as $_item): ?>
    <?php echo $this->getItemHtml($_item) ?>
   <?php endforeach; ?>
   </ol>
   <script type="text/javascript">decorateList('cart-sidebar', 'none-recursive')</script>
  <?php else: ?>
   <p class="empty"><?php echo $this->__('You have no items in your shopping cart.') ?></p>
  <?php endif ?>
```

Could someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the configurable product's image in the shopping cart in the admin under System -> Configuration -> Sales -> Checkout -> Shopping Cart:

[image: Shopping cart configurable product image, simple or parent]